# How to mock out sub-components when unit testing a React component with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I have a React component that I am trying to write some tests around.  I have broken it down to the simplest test possible.

```
jest.dontMock('../Overlay.react.js');

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var Overlay = require('../Overlay.react.js'); // this is the culprit!

describe('Overlay', () => {
    it('should work', () => {
        expect(true).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

When requiring the component I am trying to test, it seems to not be mocking its subcomponents.  At the top of `Overlay.react.js`, I have the following import: `import LoadingSpinner from 'loadingIndicator/LoadingIndicatorSpin.react';`  When running my test, I get the following error:

> - SyntaxError: /Users/dev/work/react-prototype/src/components/root/routes/components/subset1/components/Overlay.react.js:
>     /Users/dev/work/react-prototype/src/components/root/routes/components/loadingIndicator/LoadingIndicatorSpin.react.js:
>     /Users/dev/work/react-prototype/src/components/root/routes/components/loadingIndicator/sass/style.sass:
>     Unexpected token ILLEGAL

It seems like instead of mocking the components, it is going right down to the sub-component's sass file and throwing a fit.  My understanding was that Jest mocks everything except for what you tell it to *not* mock.

What is the right way to formulate these tests so that sub-components do not cause jest to explode when being imported during a test?

Comment: Slightly opinionated but I'm just thinking ahead for you. Your going to be getting many of these types of errors using jest, additionally your going to be running into performance problems when you begin to test anything non-trivial. Take a look at some open [issues](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/116) of jest and evaluate if using mocha or jasmine would be a better choice for testing framework.

Comment: Otherwise take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346687/reactjs-testing-components-containing-components) question for more guidance.

Comment: @mattclemens Interesting.  I've only really read about testing react components with jest, so that was the default.  I will read up a bit... The question you linked to is more around having subcomponents passed to the component you are trying to test, rather than them being imported it seems.

Comment: Oops, my bad for leading you an irrelevant question, I guess I picked up on that one in particular for the sub component aspect.

Comment: What else are you using to run the tests besides Jest? Are you using a transpiler e.g. Babel? And (how) is the sass stuff referenced from the JS?

Comment: @MattHolland Yes, I'm using babel (and webpack).  I'm using [sass-loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) to require my sass files directly in my component in a format such as `require('foo/bar.sass');`

Comment: Did you solve this in another way?

Comment: What do you mean by throwing a fit?

Answer (score 4):

If you would require your SASS and LESS and CSS files in the main component instead of in each sub component you would not get this problem as you test the components on their own.

There are some other solutions mentioned in this issue report if you don't like the one I provided. [Issue 334](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/334)

Comment: Requiring in the main component avoids them being imported at the lower level components, but then you can't follow the pattern of grouping a component's .js file with it's styling.  I added `if (filename.match(/.sass/) || filename.match(/.less/) || filename.match(/.css/)) {
      return '';
    }` to my preprocessor, which got past the sass error, but it seems to be pulling in every store and action when running a test for a single component (rather than mocking them all).  Jest's appeal was automocking, seems strange...

Comment: Well then I'm sorry I couldn't help. Did you checkout the issue?